Angular. Аналог ng-switch
изучаю Angular, так как он используется на проекте.
Я хотел бы знать, есть ли в Angular алтернатива NgSwitch как на javaScript switch().
Хотелось бы реализовать что-то подобное с розметкой HTML.
['Addressee','Customer','Boss','User','Dev'].forEach(function (type) {
   switch ( type ) {
      case 'Addressee':
      case 'Customer':
         console.log('Адресат и клиент');
         break;
      case 'Boss':
         console.log('Начальник');
         break;
      default:
         console.log('Другие сотрудники');
         break;
   }
});

Из документации Angular я знаю NgSwitch работает так:
Но мне совершенно не хочеться копипастить HTML для каждого выражения, при том идентичную.
<container-element [ngSwitch]="switch_expression">
  <!-- the same view can be shown in more than one case -->
  <some-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_1">...</some-element>
  <some-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_2">...</some-element>
  <some-other-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_3">...</some-other-element>
  <!--default case when there are no matches -->
  <some-element *ngSwitchDefault>...</some-element>
</container-element>

Любые советы принимаються с благодарностью=)

https://stackoverflow.com/q/40176061/4711135

Тут нужна большая конкретика, возможно, ngSwitch можно вынести в отдельный компонент или обернуть ngFor.  Может быть можно как-то еще это сделать, но для этого надо знать, как выглядит код, чтобы сделать получше
